# Alamofire upload function print the responseJSON

Tags: swift, alamofire

Here is my alamofire function...

```
        AF.upload(
            multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
                multipartFormData.append(imageData, withName: "imagePath" , fileName: "profile-image.png", mimeType: "image/png")
                for (key, value) in params {
                    multipartFormData.append((value as AnyObject).data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!, withName: key)
                    }
                print(multipartFormData.contentLength)
        },
            to: URLLink, method: .post, headers: headers)
            .downloadProgress { progress in
                print(progress)
            }
        
            .response { response in
                print(response.result)
            }
            .responseJSON(completionHandler: {data in
                print(data)
            })
```

How can I print out the response in JSON format so I can handle the responses from my server based on the information provided?

response.result and response.value doesnt do what the normal request function does.

The `.responseJSON()` does not respond with the response from the server. The data that is printed is:

```
failure(Alamofire.AFError.responseSerializationFailed(reason: Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailureReason.jsonSerializationFailed(error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Garbage at end." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Garbage at end.})))
```

BUT, its successful, the image and data is sent to the server/database.

Comment: use `.responseJSON{}`

Comment: tried that. ill post my code above @Dilan

Comment: You need to figure out why it thinks your JSON has garbage at the end, you may need to filter something out of it.

Comment: It might the response json contains more one object but not enclosed in array. Check with your backend developer and get a sample response.

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1**

Alamofire gives out of the box JSON serializer which is `responseJSON()`

```swift
    /// Adds a handler to be called once the request has finished.
    ///
    /// - parameter options:           The JSON serialization reading options. Defaults to `.allowFragments`.
    /// - parameter completionHandler: A closure to be executed once the request has finished.
    ///
    /// - returns: The request.
    @discardableResult
    public func responseJSON(
        queue: DispatchQueue? = nil,
        options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions = .allowFragments,
        completionHandler: @escaping (DownloadResponse<Any>) -> Void)
        -> Self
```

**Options 2**

`response()` is more generalised method. You can serialize the response into your own output type (JSON, String etc...).

This is the function header of `response()` method. You can specify what kind of output you need by specifying the `responseSerializer`.

```swift
    /// Adds a handler to be called once the request has finished.
    ///
    /// - parameter queue:              The queue on which the completion handler is dispatched.
    /// - parameter responseSerializer: The response serializer responsible for serializing the request, response,
    ///                                 and data contained in the destination url.
    /// - parameter completionHandler:  The code to be executed once the request has finished.
    ///
    /// - returns: The request.
    @discardableResult
    public func response<T: DownloadResponseSerializerProtocol>(
        queue: DispatchQueue? = nil,
        responseSerializer: T,
        completionHandler: @escaping (DownloadResponse<T.SerializedObject>) -> Void)
        -> Self
```

You can use this static method `DownloadRequest.jsonResponseSerializer()` to get the JSON Serializer which is required in `response()` method.

```swift
public static func jsonResponseSerializer(
        options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions = .allowFragments)
        -> DownloadResponseSerializer<Any>
```

Comment: how would these get used?